# SP13 assign page to user and show user actual name

Tags: user-profile, landing-page

I want to be able to assign a page to an individual, then in the page show anyone who is visiting who the page is maintained by.

The purpose is to enable individual pages to be updated and maintained by individual departments. If the user actual name is displayed, this will help reduce the amount of queries I get for areas outside of my main focus.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a "Pages" List with all the necassary information and then use the site creation workflow to create a site (collection?) with permissions according to a "user" or "department" field in that list.
I would prefer a site collection so every department can have its own calendar, doc library etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new person column in the library, add the user name in that field ,who will maintain  the page.
And reference that field on the page.